# How to generate 1 second clock using verilog for Artix 7 that has internal frequency of 100 MHz

Tags: verilog, clock, xilinx

I am working on Xilinx ISE, I have tried following code to get 1 second clock with 50% duty cycle.

```
module hhclock(seconds,clk,reset);

output seconds;

input clk,reset; 
reg [26:0] count;
reg temp ;

always @(posedge(clk) or posedge (reset))
begin
    if(reset)
        count<=0;
    else
        count<=count + 1'b1;
        
end
assign seconds = (count ==27'b010111110101111000010000000)?1:0;  
endmodule
```

The output is not toggling and running infinitely. Kindly share what I am doing wrong.
I don't have testbench for this. I am directly simulating.

Comment: I am trying this code only. The approach I have followed is that I have obtained period of one cycle and then run the counter to number of times to obtain  1 second cycle.

Comment: Write a testbench. Make a reasonable effort to solve this problem yourself, then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see the `seconds` signal go high, but for only one clock cycle.  Perhaps there is a problem with your simulation setup.

There are 2 problems with your code.  You only want the output to toggle when your count reaches the value you specified, and you need to reset your count value when that happens.  You should declare `seconds` as a `reg` and drive it in the `always` block as follows:

```
module hhclock (seconds,clk,reset);

output reg seconds;
input clk, reset; 
reg [26:0] count;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset) begin
        count   <= 0;
        seconds <= 0;
    end else if (count == 27'd50_000_000) begin 
        count   <= 0;
        seconds <= ~seconds;
    end else begin
        count   <= count + 1'b1;    
    end 
end

endmodule
```

Note: I use the decimal value (`50_000_000`) instead of your long string of 1's and 0's since it is more meaningful in this case.

[image]